# 'tangentopoli', 'concorsopoli', 'sanitopoli', and so on

Tags: suffix

I observed that Italian journalists use to coin new words using the suffix '-poli', as in *tangentopoli*, *sanitopoli*, *concorsopoli* and so on.

I cannot think of a case in which those new words, which are conied day-by-day in reference to limitless cases of corruction, have a positive connotation.

So my question is: Is it possible that Italian journalists use those *poli*-words evoking, etymologically, a parallel with the Disney's Paperopoli? If not, can anyone explain what the origin of this 'poli' is?

Comment: Just to be a full-time nit-picker, “Paperopoli” can't rightfully be defined “Disney's”, both because in English it is called Duckburg, and because most of the duck-related original mythology was due to Carl Barks. Quack!

Comment: It's interesting to notice that the usage of the "-poli" suffix for corruption/scandals mimicking *tangentopoli* is the exact equivalent of the american "-gate" originating from *Watergate*.

Comment: It's just a way to say "city of" or, in an extended sense "system/group of", and it is not always used with a negative connotation. It's of course journalistic jargon, but it does not com from Disney, neither it has always a dispregiative sense.

Answer (score 12):

[*-poli* is](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/poli_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) a [suffixoid](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/suffissoide/); it comes from Greek *polis* (*city*), and it is used as a suffix: *baraccopoli* (city of slums), *tangentopoli* (city of corruption), etc.

Actually *Paperopoli* is a good example of a positive use of the suffix *-poli*, although this is [generally](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/poli_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) used to coin terms of negative connotation.

*Fonopoli*, the name of Renato Zero's project, is another case where *-poli* is used to coin a positive connotation word.

Other words without a negative connotation are: *metropoli*, *acropoli*, *necropoli*, *cosmopoli*, *megalopoli*.

Answer (score 8):

This *-poli* device was born when the “Tangentopoli” scandal was at its beginnings in 1992, when Milan was considered “the city of bribes.” After that, almost every scandal was boringly named with a *-poli* suffix.

The suffix has been used in the past, as witnessed by *Constantinopolis* (Greek *Κωνσταντινούπολις*), the town founded by emperor Constantine near *Byzantium* (Greek *Βυζάντιον*), currently İstanbul, Turkey. The Italian translation *Paperopoli* of Disney's Duckburg came quite late and with many models from the past.

Comment: This is not true. Tangentopoli has been the most resilient and the best known of such neologisms, but far from being the first one.
Baraccopoli and tendopoli for example, have been in use for way longer than tangentopoli.

Comment: @Bruno9779 *Baraccopoli* and *tendopoli* don't have the scandal related meaning. I didn't say "suffix", but "device".

Comment: Baraccopoli and tendopoli have negative nuances and mean something like shanty town.
The OP does not imply scandal in his question, and the suffix -polis is neutral. The negative nuance is given by "tangenti", bribes.

Comment: @Bruno9779 All the examples by the OP are names of scandals.

Comment: Paperopoli is a scandal?

Comment: @Bruno9779 I can't understand what you're objecting to: the OP is talking about scandal names in *-poli* and asks whether there is a parallel with “Paperopoli”. So my reading is that he's interested in why scandals are named with the suffix.

Comment: I see the OP asking if works ending with -poli come from Paperopoli. He also says he can't think of a positive meaning for a word ending in -poli.
In the end, you can read scandal or not, but it is irrelevant when answering the question.

Comment: @Bruno9779 So, where's the problem? By the way, I see little negative meaning in *baraccopoli* (it just asserts a reality), none in *tendopoli*. My answer dealt with the suffix attached for scandals names, telling it doesn't parallel *Paperopoli*. What more?

Comment: The question has been answered a while back. You insist on seeing a scandal meaning to this question and it is your problem. Let's close this argument here

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, which clearly and correctly identify the suffix *–poli* as meaning *city*, I would like an interesting historical point. The suffix can be used in two different ways:

1. in common words, like *baraccópoli*;
2. part of proper nouns, like *Napoli* or *Costantinopoli*.

*Tangentopoli* originally was an example of 2., because it was a nickname for Milan (*"City of bribes"*). *Paperopoli* is also another example of use in this sense.

After the corruption scandal became such a huge issue, the meaning of the suffix actually changed, and is now used in a manner similar to the English *–gate* suffix, which started with a proper name (*Watergate*) and was then extended to [many other scandals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scandals_with_%22-gate%22_suffix).

In this sense, *–poli* is used in common words now, an usage which is called *accidental usage*, but it has lost the meaning of city, just like *–gate* has lost any geographical connotation. It just means *large scandal*.

A funny side note. The proper noun of the game *Monópoli* is pronounced with a second-last vowel accent like a proper city name. This is to imitate the English game name of *Monopoly*. In reality, the word *monopólio* does not use the suffix *–poli* but the suffix *–polio* which means *vendor*. In fact, the old spelling of the plural *monopóli* should be *monopolii*, *monopolĳ* or *monopolî*.

Normally, in Italian *–poli* never takes an accent.

---

References:

- Treccani, [-Poli](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/poli_res-63e6a5dd-002a-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/), Vocabolario on line

Comment: I second the form *monopolî* for the plural of *monopolio*, the more so since *monopoli* is the plural of *monopolo* (i.e., a (magnetic) monopole).

Comment: Monopoli is an actual city in the province of Bari. And the use of the ^ accent is practically dead in modern Italian.