# Traduzione elegante di "Product Backlog"

Tags: translation

Mi sto arrovellando per trovare una traduzione elegante di "Product Backlog". Si tratta di un concetto della programmazione agile che indica un elenco delle caratteristiche di un prodotto software che non sono ancora soddisfatte.

In generale nella letteratura specializzata si tende a lasciare il termine inglese, ma forse è possibile fare meglio. Ho pensato ad alcune soluzioni ma nessuna mi entusiasma.

"Ordinativi del prodotto" 
"Ordinativi arretrati/inevasi del prodotto"
"Preordini del prodotto"

Comment: @kos: Pragmaticamente quello che dici è impeccabile, ma non solo plaudo anch'io al tentativo di piffy, ma mi chiedo anche se sia così ineluttabile aver bisogno di anglismi. Dopo tutto anche in inglese quel concetto, il giorno prima che venisse coniata una parola nuova o risemantizzata una parola esistente, avrebbe avuto bisogno di una lunga spiegazione. Quindi perché non potremmo anche noi creare parole nuove (“retrotrasporto” nel caso di “backport”?) o dare nuovi significati a quelle vecchie (come si è fatto per “cartella”, “compilare”, “sorgente” e varie altre)?

Comment: E per dare un abbozzo di risposta: usare qualcosa come “arretrati del prodotto”, sfruttando l'uso sostantivato già esistente di “arretrati”?

Comment: @DaG Verissimo. Quello a cui pensavo è a quanto "impatto" finisce per avere il termine coniato, in funzione di quanto il "compattare" concetti interi in parole singole sia un costrutto accettabile; in Inglese "compattare" concetti interi in parole singole è talmente diffuso da essere abusato, o almeno mi sembra (non so, concordi?) (prendi un qualcosa che fa scalpore ed aggiungici "gate": nuova parola), tant'è che per qualcuno uso alla lingua forse semplicemente piove sul bagnato; comunque questa è solo un'impressione. Sono così d'accordo col tuo commento che ho rimosso il mio precedente.

Comment: @kos Grazie, ma non c'era bisogno! Penso che sia difficile confrontare le “efficienze” lessicali dell'inglese e dell'italiano. Dopo tutto anche in italiano abbiamo un suffisso fertile come “[-poli](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/tangentopoli-concorsopoli-sanitopoli-and-so-on)”, che è un po' l'analogo di “-gate”.

Comment: @Walter però "coda delle azioni" non è che suoni granché bene...

Comment: Ho cancellato i miei precedenti commenti perché ho scoperto che _backlog_ è sì percepito in inglese essenzialmente come "_retrodiario_" (e questa era la mia proposta di traduzione provocatoria), ma che probabilmente era già usato per denotare gli arretrati prima ancora che il _log-book_ ("libro del ciocco", dove il ciocco era quello che veniva gettato in acqua legato ad una sagola per misurare la velocità della nave) diventasse il generico _log_ (registro, diario). Il _backlog_ era il ciocco sul fondo (retro) del focolare, il più lento a bruciare, il "contrario" del _forestick_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faccio una proposta che può andar bene in certi casi e che ha, secondo me, una sua eleganza:

**agenda del prodotto**

Answer (score 3):

Credo che la traduzione di termini specialistici debba essere uniforme e riconoscibile dai propri utenti[1]. Altrimenti si rischia di confonderli, anche per concetti semplici. Ad esempio, se nella traduzione dell'interfaccia di un sito invece di scegliere *account* si usasse la sua traduzione *conto*, penso che molte persone rimarrebbero interdette, perché non è quello che si aspettano. Probabilmente penserebbero ad un *conto in banca*.

Per questo personalmente uso il [Portale linguistico di Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/it-it/Search.aspx?sString=backlog&langID=it-it) per conoscere come viene generalmente tradotto un termine. In questo caso suggerisce di usare *backlog di prodotto*.

Cercherei una traduzione più "italianeggiante" se gli usufruitori della stessa non fossero professionisti del settore, ad esempio se fosse parte di un documento didattico per studenti alle prime armi o uno da sottoporre a dirigenti per approvazione.

Venendo ad una possibile traduzione io proverei con:

- desiderata del prodotto/software
- priorità del prodotto/software
- criteri del prodotto/software

[1] non sono un traduttore professionista, quindi potrei sbagliarmi

Comment: Infatti si tratta proprio di un prodotto didattico :-) Mi piace assai "desiderata", che è un po' il senso reale della cosa - non tanto degli "ordini" quanto quello che si vorrebbe ottenere.
Il portale Microsoft, come altri tool online, spesso però agisce da "volano negativo": se c'è in giro una brutta traduzione, non fa che diffonderla di più :-)

Comment: Come ho detto non ho pretese di professionalità, ho solo la mia esperienza di traduttore amatoriale di progetti open source. In questi casi, dove è difficile coordinarsi, il portale Microsoft, e simili, fa da àncora per garantire un minimo di uniformità. Devo ammettere che di solito sono proprio io a usare termini italiani ovunque, e altri mi hanno fatto notare che così le persone non capivano di cosa si stesse parlando.

Answer (score 0):

Come suggerito da Gabriele, tradurre l'espressione potrebbe portare a più incomprensioni che il contrario.

Essendo una parola senza corrispettivo diretto, direi che vada tradotta con un'espressione. Informalmente un buon candidato potrebbe essere "lista delle cose da fare".

Renderla più formale richiederebbe usare termini un po' desueti come appunto "desiderata" ("lista delle desiderata").

Letteralmente di traduce come "traccia scritta degli arretrati", ma cercare un adattamento letterale non è una buona opzione in questo caso.

In generale, cercherei di mantenere il termine "lista", in quanto enfatizza il fatto che le "task" siano ordinate (per priorità).

Answer (score 0):

Pensando anche all'aspetto "commerciale" della possibile soluzione, suggerirei "perfezionamento in corso".